# VBA Download xlsx file from Website (DMS or EDM)

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx, getfiles

It is with a poor level in VBA that I seek your expertise on this problem, having traversed without success the various subjects similar to mine.
Indeed, I want to download an .xlsx file from a website (or Document Management System). 
The site link is as follows: https://www.mezzoteam.com/login.aspx with authentication required.

The following code is used to connect to the website with the connection parameters and to access the page where the file to be downloaded is contained :

```
Sub GetTable_GED()

'Renseigner le lien de la page de connexion et la page du taleau à récupérer
Const cURL = "https://www.mezzoteam.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2flayout_documents.aspx"
Const cURL2 = "https://www.mezzoteam.com/window_document.aspx?&wsfromlink=22e58a2a-fa83-4462-9b30-1768498b67e6&id=ffc12ca9-1333-4b35-b5eb-7d3857f00b70"

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

'Créer une nouvelle fenetre dans le navigateur
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

'Activer le débogage de la page
IE.Visible = True

'Lancer la page
IE.navigate cURL

'Chargement initial de la page

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set Doc = IE.document

'Identifier la structure de la page
Set LoginForm = Doc.forms(0)

'Remplir les paramètres de connexion de type username, password
'input name="ctl00$body$userName" id="ctl00_body_userName" class="form-control" placeholder="email@example.com" autocomplete="username" type="email"
'<input name="ctl00$body$password" type="password" id="ctl00_body_password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password">

With Doc

  .getElementById("ctl00_body_userName").Value = "xxxxxxxx@xxxx.com"
  .getElementById("ctl00_body_password").Value = "xxxxxxx"

  'Executer en cliquant le bouton de connexion
'<input type="submit" name="ctl00$body$LoginButton" value="Se connecter" id="ctl00_body_LoginButton" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">

  .getElementsByName("ctl00$body$LoginButton")(0).Click

End With

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

'Maintenant, allons dans la page où se trouve le tableau à récupérer
IE.navigate cURL2
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set objElement = IE.document

With objElement

'<button id="ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_actionsbar_download" type="button" value="download" class="btn btn-primary"><span id="ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_actionsbar_download_label">Télécharger</span> </button>

.getElementById("ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_actionsbar_download").Click **click buton to download file**

End With

End Sub
```

'''

At this stage, the download does not run ! I have this message error : 
"Execution error 438: Property or method not managed by this object" from code `.getElementById("ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_actionsbar_download").Click`

My need : download this .xlsx file and open it in a active sheet workbook.

I also attach in pictures the page in which the file is targeted and as well as the HTML code highlighting the file to download.

[HTML code page where file contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt2Jg.png)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

So this `.getElementsById("yui-gen1000018")(0).Click` suggests that the method you're using would return a collection of elements that share the same `id`. From this collection you would like to click the 1st element.

**However**, there is no such method as `.getElementsById()`. The method you're looking for is `.getElementById()` and returns a **single** element with the `id` specified instead of a collection of elements. Keep in mind that the `id` of an HTML element should be unique.

So, if the element you're interested in clicking actually has a unique `id` which is `yui-gen1000018`, then the way to click it would be:

`.getElementById("yui-gen1000018").Click`

Comment: Thank you @Stavros for your return, I tried this '''.getElementsById("yui-gen1000018").Click''' but the same runtime error '462' is still displayed. Can you please, look on this screenshot for the HTML structure of the page where the file to download is located? and if possible correct my code. Thank you

Comment: @NarcisseD. Like I said `.getElementsById()` is wrong.  The right way is `.getElementById()`. **Element** not **Elements**. Without an **s**.

Comment: Thanks @Stavros. I used `.getElementById()` but there is no change (I tried with different id of Element). On my main post, I submitted an image containing the HTML code of the page and highlighting the file to download. Please can you look it ?

Comment: Please have you reviewed my problem ? I have not been advancing for 15 days. Please help me